# Sending Release APK to Server

Tags: codenameone

How do I send a release APK of my app to the CodeNameOne build server instead of a debug APK? In my build hints I have `android.debug=false`

Please let me know if you need more information, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a certificate, we have wizards to generate a certificate for Android/iOS/Windows UWP in the Codename One Settings app.